# Sharepoint Linked Document Library

Tags: document-library, document

A little Background:
We are a design shop that uses Autocad a lot.  We also use sharepoint.  They do not work well together!  Both are awesome products and we need a solution!

We create a sub-site for each of our projects.  The sub-site is created using a template site and that site contains a document library.  Inside that document library we store our drawing files, customer information and such.  This works "OK" with the exception that the engineers need to use one drive sync to every single sub-site document library to maintain the drawing files.

Our Thoughts:
What if we could create one MASTER repository just for drawings and link a folder in the sub-site document library to a "Master" document library that has 100% of the drawings and is arranged by project number.  We use the document Library to store lots of documents, but we have a single folder today that is just for drawing files.  If we could link that to site\MasterDrawingLibrary\%PROJECTNUMBER%  somehow we would solve a problem for us and for many people that use autocad and sharepoint toghether!

Answer (score 1):

In your document library, you can go into the Advanced Settings and set the "Allow management of content types?" option to Yes. Then you'd add the Link to a Document content type to the list. Then it's simply adding a new item based off this content type to point to the desired location.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you can use [Cross Site Publishing](http://blogs.technet.com/b/tothesharepoint/archive/2013/02/19/an-introduction-to-cross-site-publishing.aspx) feature of the SharePoint 2013. I think this feature fulfill your requirement.